# Suddenly, scrapy stops working

Tags: python, scrapy

I was using scrapy framework which is running fine. But suddenly today when i crawl my spider, i experience this error

> 2018-06-25 21:33:22 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.5.0 started
>   (bot: sam_amazon) Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\sa\Anaconda3\Scripts\scrapy-script.py", line 5, in 
>       sys.exit(scrapy.cmdline.execute())   File "C:\Users\sa\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\cmdline.py", line 149,
>   in execute
>       cmd.crawler_process = CrawlerProcess(settings)   File "C:\Users\sa\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 252,
>   in **init**
>       log_scrapy_info(self.settings)   File "C:\Users\sa\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\log.py", line
>   149, in log_scrapy_info
>       for name, version in scrapy_components_versions()   File "C:\Users\sa\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\versions.py",
>   line 35, in scrapy_components_versions
>       ("pyOpenSSL", _get_openssl_version()),   File "C:\Users\sa\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\versions.py",
>   line 43, in _get_openssl_version
>       import OpenSSL   File "C:\Users\sa\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\OpenSSL__init__.py", line 8,
>   in 
>       from OpenSSL import crypto, SSL   File "C:\Users\sa\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\OpenSSL\crypto.py", line 16,
>   in 
>       from OpenSSL._util import (   File "C:\Users\sa\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\OpenSSL_util.py", line 6, in
>   
>       from cryptography.hazmat.bindings.openssl.binding import Binding   File
>   "C:\Users\sa\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\openssl\binding.py",
>   line 13, in 
>       from cryptography.hazmat.bindings._openssl import ffi, lib ImportError: DLL load failed: The operating system cannot run %1.

I have tried to uninstall and install scrapy again. But it did not work. Please help. I am stuck with this error.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please download , 
 https://github.com/python/cpython-bin-deps/tree/openssl-bin-1.0.2k 
unzip it and copy it to

In your sys path : C:\Windows\SysWOW64?

This seems like openssl error on windows

> `**line 13**, in from cryptography.hazmat.bindings._openssl import ffi, lib ImportError: DLL load failed: The operating system cannot run %1.`

Comment: I have tried your solution. But still, it is showing the same error.

Answer (score 0):

My Problem is solved by installing the previous version of openssl.